# Resources to learn to deploy Java EE applications

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web-deployment

I want to learn about application deployment, specifically Java EE apps. But I don't know where to start and what learning path should i have.

I've been building Java EE applications for over 2 years at enterprise companies. But the deployment layer of the app has been hidden from me and done by other teams, we just give them our ear file and it gets magically deployed.

I feel like a good Java EE developer should know this stuff, so I'm looking for some recommended material or learning path guidelines. FYI My experience in deployment is basically 0, I've deployed a webpage on a hosting site once.

Comment: You're right that a good developer knows more than just how to write code, but this is way too broad to be answered here. I recommend spending copious amounts of time at Google (the search engine, not the company).

Comment: A lot of googling is the plan, but i'm hoping for a kick start here with some guidelines, or resources ( books, articles etc. )  Or broad guidelines on what should i know first before diving in.

Comment: There are dozens of deployment tools, dozens of application servers. Each one with its own quirks. You can't learn them without actually using them, and it takes a long time. Pick a tool and a server and see if you can get your app deployed (it's not really that hard, most servers allow you to just copy a WAR to a specific directory for deployment).

Answer (score 0):

For deploying J2EE application, you can start by creating war file and deploying it on a running Tomcat server.
For getting started you can have a look at this documentation of tomcat.

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/deployer-howto.html